# Nested resources, list siblings on the same page as 'create' form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, exception, activerecord, nested

I have a nested resource, not dis-similar from the 'post' / 'comments' relationship you'd find on a blog.

On my #show event for the post, I display a form for a new comment and below it are all the previous comments for that post.

My #show method within the controller looks something like this:

```
def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @post.comments.build
```

Now, the problem with this is that I now have an empty, unsaved entity inside my @page.comments collection. As a result within my view when I'm listing the comments and I do something like.

```
<%= comment.created_at.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S") %>
```

I get an exception thrown:

```
undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass
```

I have tried to rectify this by switching my #show controller so that it doesn't scope the new comment through the post object but I still run back into the same problem if I'm redirected back to the form with a validation error.

Can anyone offer some advice?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same problem.  There doesn't seem to be a legit way to build the child object through the collection without actually adding it to the collection.

So instead of:

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
@comment = @post.comments.build
```

I do:

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
@comment = Comment.new(:post => @post)
```

It builds the child object in the same way, but doesn't add it to the parent collection so your list builds without error.  It's not how I would like to do it, but it appears to be the best way to accomplish the same thing with the minimum amount of change to the workflow.